# Rotating picture from android camera

Tags: android, camera, orientation, android-camera

I'm setting rotation for camera:

```
stopPreview();
Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
p.setRotation(90);
mCamera.setParameters(p);
startPreview();
```

Photo is taken when device is in horizontal orientation. I need photo rotated to vertical orientation. But when I'm saving jpeg it is never rotated, it's always horizontal.

```
protected void onJpegPicture(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
    saveJpeg(data, file);
}
```

Am I missing something? I don't think I should manually rotate picture after taking it. I think camera should be able to do this for me.

`setRotation` parameter doesn't matter. I tried all possible values (0, 90, 180, 270).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet you have should work, assuming you call setParameters() before calling takePicture(). You could try setting the parameters right before your takePicture call, instead of before starting preview, but that should not matter.

Note that you probably don't want to use 90 here, since the orientation of the picture is determined relative to the orientation of the sensor, not to your current UI orientation. And whether the sensor is aligned with portrait or landscape depends on your device - you can check this with [CameraInfo.orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#orientation). Nevertheless, you should see an effect if you've tried all the rotation values.

Which devices are you seeing this behavior on? Also, how are you viewing the final image? Some image viewers still don't interpret the JPEG rotation field correctly, though any on-device gallery app really should (especially if it's the default application).

Comment: I don't need correct rotation now, I want rotation at all - that way I used 90 as rotation (and tried other constant values).
This doesn't work on sony xperia. I found in the Internet that this is common problem with other phones too. Manufacturers doesn't fulfill android requirements about photo rotation.
Doesn't matter if I take picture when my phone is oriented horizontal or vertical and doesn't matter which rotation I set I always get picture oriented horizontal.

Comment: We've added better tests for this in the newer Android releases, so at least newer devices should not exhibit these issues any more.

Answer (score 2):

Try rotating both camera and it's preview. i.e.

```
//rotate preview
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
//rotate camera
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setRotation(90);
camera.setParameters(p);
```

Tested on several HTC devices and it works.

Comment: Yes its working with my Samsung Galaxy S4 also. Is it device dependent?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method by passing to it the `Image` itself and the `rotation degree` that is 90 in your case

```
public static Image rotate(Image img, double angle){
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
    int w = img.getWidth(null), h = img.getHeight(null);
    int neww = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin), newh = (int) Math.floor(h
        * cos + w * sin);
    BufferedImage bimg = toBufferedImage(getEmptyImage(neww, newh));
    Graphics2D g = bimg.createGraphics();
    g.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
    g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w / 2, h / 2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(toBufferedImage(img), null);
    g.dispose();
    return toImage(bimg);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do this manually. Rotating image by 90x is an easy task, so all methods able to rotate by any degree are too complex for this. Furthermore android devices has low memory. I don't want to keep two copies of img (before and after rotation) in memory. I don't want to waste time to save and load img from drive.

Comment: There is not good way to solve your problem. `setRotation` doesn't guarantee that image is rotated properly. You should resize your images manually.